# Why does nginx+passenger not find some gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why does nginx+passenger fail to start and print this into error.log?

```
Could not find addressable-2.3.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
 /usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92...
```

My RoR app is installed in /var/www/html/ and I ran bin/bundle from that directory:

```
$ bin/bundle install --deployment
Using addressable 2.3.6...
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
```

The gem is under vendor/bundle:

```
$ ls vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ | grep address
addressable-2.3.6
```

Part of Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    addressable (2.3.6)...
```

Nginx passenger configuration in /etc/nginx/conf.d/passenger.conf:

```
passenger_root /usr/local/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.53/;
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby; ...
```

nginx site configuration in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf

```
passenger_enabled on;
passenger_set_cgi_param RAILS_ENV production;
```

I tried setting `passenger_set_cgi_param GEM_PATH /var/www/html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/:/usr/local/share/gems/gems/;` but then I get this error:

```
Message from application: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'...
```

Comment: As a workaround, removed rvm